# js -- code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'

Tags: javascript, ssl, fetch

У меня есть простенький запрос API из POSTMAN который выдает ошибку SSL. В PHP это решалось добавлением CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false. Как это сделать в js?

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW478378378273cmdrNiFAIzQ=");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "SoapSession.id=C0F96erererDB11671548137398; JSESSIONID=243FEB15643ererre8E1144D0E73E0C; JSESSIONIDSSO=D546EDererer5A5332EA92A18CFC80");

var raw = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap\">\r\n   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n   <soapenv:Body>\r\n      <soap:selectCmDevice>\r\n         <soap:StateInfo></soap:StateInfo>\r\n         <soap:CmSelectionCriteria>\r\n            <soap:MaxReturnedDevices>1000</soap:MaxReturnedDevices>\r\n            <soap:DeviceClass>Phone</soap:DeviceClass>\r\n            <soap:Model>684</soap:Model>\r\n            <soap:Status>Any</soap:Status>\r\n            <soap:NodeName>uc-ucm-1.domain.com</soap:NodeName>\r\n            <soap:SelectBy>DirNumber</soap:SelectBy>\r\n            <soap:SelectItems>\r\n               <soap:item>\r\n                  <soap:Item></soap:Item>\r\n               </soap:item>\r\n            </soap:SelectItems>\r\n            <soap:Protocol>Any</soap:Protocol>\r\n            <soap:DownloadStatus>Any</soap:DownloadStatus>\r\n         </soap:CmSelectionCriteria>\r\n      </soap:selectCmDevice>\r\n   </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://uc-ucm-1.domain.com:8443/realtimeservice2/services/RISService70", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
error TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1538:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:952:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:733:12) {
    code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
  }
}
```

Comment: Заранее вручную добавить сертификат в доверенные в настройках браузера

Comment: Из Safari и Chrome, в том то и дело, сервер открывается без проблем, я в VSCode запускаю

Comment: Что конкретно вы в VSCode запускаете? Вы имеете в виду node.js?

Comment: В POSTMAN скрипт выше идет как JavaScript - Fetch. Просто скопировал в VSCode, файл обозвал file.js и через Code Runner пытаюсь запустить. В PHP аналогичный скрипт с добавлением CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false без проблемно работает